# An efficient algorithm to compute the number of '1' bit in a long decimal integer that is represented in string?

Tags: algorithm

I came across this interesting question today. (Note that this is not for my homework or interview, etc.)

Given a decimal number that is represented in string, we want to compute the number of `'1'` bits for the large number in binary format.  Here the string can have thousands of characters, and cannot be represented with one int or long long variable.

For example,  `countBits("10") = 2` as `'10'` in decimal can be represented as `'1010'` in binary format. Similarly, we have `countBits("12") = 2`, `countBits("7") = 3`

What is an efficiently algorithm for this?  One possible solution is to convert the decimal string to another string in the binary format, and count the '1's. Can we do better?

Comment: "*and count the '1's*" - The question is how do you count the 1's. See my answer.

Comment: Please specify, what do you mean by LARGE number

Comment: @MBo  I've updated the question. Basically, the input string can be very long, and it cannot fit into an int, or long long data type.

Comment: Unclear.  Count the bits in the equivalent binary representation of an extraordinarily long decimal number, or count the bits in the binary representation of the individual decimal digits.  If the former then it's a non-trivial problem -- not something that would likely be expressed in a 20-line reply here.

Answer (score 1):

When converting from a decimal representation to and integer, the *n*th digit from the end of the string represents the number of 10<sub>10</sub><sup>*n*</sup>  ( one zero base ten to the power of n ) that is added to total the integer value. If you then want to represent that integer in binary, you have to raise 10<sub>10</sub> which is 1010<sub>2</sub> to that power and multiply that value by the digit's value.

Because one of the factors of the base you are translating from, 5, is relatively prime compared to 2, the powers of 10<sub>10</sub> have increasing long representations in base 2 - 1<sub>2</sub>, 1010<sub>2</sub>, 1100100<sub>2</sub>, 1111101000<sub>2</sub>.

Note that these powers have trailing zeros ( 10<sub>10</sub> = 2 × 5 and 2 is not relatively prime with the base we are translating into ), so will only effect 1, 3, 5, and 7 bits of the answer instead of all 1, 4, 7, 10 bits. But the number of bits they effect will still vary with O(N) where N is the length of the input, so to calculate the effected bits will take O(N<sup>2</sup>) operations.

If the base you were translating from did not have factors where were relatively prime to the base you are translating to - say translating base 16 to base 2 or base 9 to base 3 and counting non-zero digits, then there would be a O(N) algorithm as the sum of non-zero digits in the target base would equal the sum for each digit in the input translated individually, but since that is not the case then you are stuck at an O(N<sup>2</sup>) algorithm where you translate the decimal representation into binary and then count the bits in the binary representation.

Answer (score 0):

You convert it to *binary* and use [Hamming weight algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight).

How it works? Suppose you have the number 8, which is 00001000.

The algorithm takes chunks of 2 *bits*, so it'll have 00 00 10 00. 
Now it'll sum each two *bits* (by having a mask 10101010, multiplying and shifting), which will result: 00 00 01 00.

Now it does the same for each 4 *bits* (by having a mask 00110011..), so it'll have 0000 1000. After adding each side, you'll have 0000 00001.

The last stage is adding the two numbers, 0 + 1, which is 1 and that's the final result.

Comment: What is time complexity to convert an arbitrary long decimal string to binary? Can it be O(n)?

Comment: I guess it'll be O(n) since you have to iterate on all the characters in the String..

Comment: @yuyang - The time complexity of converting an arbitrarily long decimal number to binary is actually N squared, since you have to multiply increasingly longer numbers.